# My database class is too big/poor coding, how can I make this better?

Tags: java, mysql, gwt

I'm developing a GWT program, connected to a MySQL database. Let me preface by saying I'm fairly far into this, and I don't know struts, or hibernate or the like. My database calls have become large and I'd like to change that to a better practice. Things have seem to have gotten convoluted.

In my `databaseServiceImpl` class I have a series of methods that each do one thing (add client, delete client, add product, add order, etc) which means I now have 50+ methods, all somewhat similar but different results or objects used. 
here is an example of a method from this class

```
    @Override
public int addClient(Client client) throws DatabaseException {
    Connection con = connect();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    int clientID = 0;
    // insert client into client table
    try {
        String query = "INSERT INTO clients (clientID, name, description, notes, address, contactName, contactNumber) VALUES (" + "NULL,'"
                + client.getClientName() + "','" + client.getDescription() + "','" + client.getNotes() + "','" + client.getAddress() + "','"
                + client.getContactName() + "','" + client.getContactNumber() + "')";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        System.out.println("addClient: " + ps.toString());
        clientID = ps.executeUpdate(query, ps.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        con.commit();
        System.out.println("Transactions are being committed.");
        while (rs.next()) {
            clientID = rs.getInt(1);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        try {
            con.rollback();
            System.out.println("Transactions are being rolled back.");
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        throw new DatabaseException(e);
    } finally {
        close(rs, ps, con);
    }
    return clientID;
}
```

Ok, maybe this wouldn't be so bad, but every time I call a method from the dataservice (even for something small) I end up needing this,

```
Ioma.dataservice.addClient(name.getText(), desc.getText(), notes.getText(), address.getText(), contactName.getText(),
phone.getText(), new AsyncCallback<Integer>() {
@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
    new GuiErrorDialog("Add Client", caught);
}
@Override
public void onSuccess(Integer result) {
    Window.alert("Client " + name.getText() + " added");
    }
});
```

Which seems excessive to me for simple queries and results. I understand that database calls in GWT are asynchronous calls but I can't help but feel I'm following incorrect or poor coding practices. What can I do to make this better?

Comment: This might be better suited for codereview or another website since there is currently no error in the code.

Comment: Ouch, queries "parameterized" _via_ string concat! Use real parameterization (see [example in javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)) to guard against SQL-injection. Try entering `'); DROP TABLE clients;--` in your "phone" field.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs - how common/probable is that the query will fail? If it fails, can you (or the user) do something about it? Maybe a generic error message is enough? The user doesn't have to know that it was an *Exception at line x - it should suffice to say that something unexpected happened. You (the developer/maintainer) should monitor the logs and react accordingly to the errors. You should take care on the client-side (validate the input, etc.) so that no error occurs on the server-side - unless something explodes, of course :)

As for making the code less bloated - a lot can be done, of course. For queries, I can't recommend enough [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/). The open-source version supports MySQL and there's excellent support right here on SO via the [jooq](/questions/tagged/jooq) tag. jOOQ allows writing type-safe queries using Java - you can easily re-use parts of the queries, etc. No more writing queries as strings!

For the client-side callbacks - you could create a subclass of `AsyncCallback` that has `onFailure` implemented with some generic message (the message could be the callback's constructor parameter if it has to be different per callback).

If you're doing a lot of [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations, maybe [RequestFactory](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html) would be a better fit?